# White space not removing after using normalized-space in XSLT

Tags: xslt, whitespace, space, removing-whitespace

Following is my code written in XSLT:

```
<FIELD>
    <ID>ID</ID>
    <VALUE>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Name)"/>
    </VALUE>
</FIELD>
```

Actual Output:

```
<FIELD>
    <ID>ID</ID>
    <VALUE>  JonSnow </VALUE>
</FIELD>
```

Expected Output:

```
<FIELD>
    <ID>ID</ID>
    <VALUE>JonSnow</VALUE>
</FIELD>
```

How can I remove that unwanted space in VALUE tag in XSLT? I have already coded normalize-space here?

Comment: Please show us the input, so that we can try and reproduce the problem. Also add the context to your XSLT.

Comment: actually i am getting $name from java and displaying same in xslt for SAP PO. but after this there is comparison is there between this value i think due to space in the value comparison is not working.

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you mean. If you don't provide a way to reproduce your problem, then no good answer is possible - see: [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT: Remove excess whitespace characters preserving nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938704/xslt-remove-excess-whitespace-characters-preserving-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- Identity Transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="VALUE">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i never worked in xslt.  could you please add the code in my code and give me working code?

Comment: @Coder1  as i am not aware of what code you use, but you can check with <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(VALUE)"/> or <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>

Comment: @Coder1 also as you comment that you get value in variable then you can use <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($name)"/>

Comment: <xsl:param name="NAme">
<xsl:value-of select="string(NAme)" />
</xsl:param>      <xsl:variable name="ID">       <xsl:if test="function-available('javamap:Method_Name')">         <xsl:value-of select="javamap:Method_Name($INAme,$inputparam)" /></xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
<!-- Java Enhancement for method End -->
            <FIELD>
              <ID>ID</ID>
              <VALUE>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($ID)"/>
              </VALUE>
            </FIELD>

Comment: this is the scenario.

Comment: It may be possible that your input contain non-breaking-space try to change <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($ID)"/> to <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace($ID, '&#160;', ' '))"/>

Comment: why should use replace function with normalize-space

Comment: @AjeetSingh because normalize function doesn't remove non breaking spaces.

Comment: @Rupesh can variable value should be allow normalize-space

Comment: @AjeetSingh Yes