# XSLT fn:normalize-space() deletes all xml-tags

Tags: xslt, formatting

I'm a novice when it comes to XSLT and I've tried to find the information but not really sure what to search after.

I'm trying to remove the whitespace before and after the value in each node with the `fn-normalize-space()` function. It works, but also removes all XML tags.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

<root>
  <order>
     <customer> The Company    </customer>
  </order>
</root>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I want to achieve here is to remove the whitespace before and after the value in the `<customer>` tag, but at the same time preserve the XML tags.

Comment: `normalize-space` is an XPath function that works on strings and returns a string so if you pass in a node it takes the string value of the node and normalizes that string value. It is not clear what exactly you want to achieve, other than perhaps simply using `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` or perhaps simply only using `normalize-space` on text nodes with e.g. `<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></xsl:template>`. Show us a sample of the input and the wanted output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin. I updated my question with a sample.

Comment: Well, in the sample you have now shown the element you have presented is part of the XSLT code and not even an input element in some XML document the XSLT processes.  So it seems you should just write the stylesheet code without the white space. If you had the `customer` element in an XML and wanted to transform it with XSLT you would use `<xsl:template match="customer"><xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it's a duplicate, and if so, of [XSLT - remove whitespace from template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1468984/11683) or of [XSLT: Remove excess whitespace characters preserving nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37938704/11683).

Comment: Oh, that was stupid of me. But say if I use the following line. What do I replace it with to remove the whitespace?

  <customer><xsl:value-of select="/root/order/company"/></customer>

Comment: You can use the `normalize-space()` function to do that. Syntax is `<customer><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(/root/order/company)"/></customer>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it with an XPath as Martin Honnen described. This code should output an exact copy of your xml without whitespaces:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to apply it on a specific XPath and not on all textnodes you would use it like:

```
<xsl:template match="nodename">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(specificNodename)"/>
</xsl:template>
```